# FPDF - Generating multiple PDFs

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Note the code below (a sanitized version of my code), which is currently working.

The code pulls variables from the database, puts them into a PDF template and outputs a PDF file that has form fields, filled in with the variabes.

Towards the end of the code, there is a loop that I put in. I am wanting it to generate a PDF for each row in the database. Unfortunately this only generates one pdf. The loop is working fine on it's own, so I gather this is more about FPDF's limitations.

Is there a way I can achieve this in one script?

```
<?php
    // Requires
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
    require('fpdm/fpdm.php');
    // Mysql Connection
    $host = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $database = "";
    $con = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database); 

    if ($con->connect_error) 
    {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $uniqueID_1 = $_GET['uniqueID_1'];

    // Loop starts here
    if($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE uniqueID_1 = '" . $uniqueID_1 . "'"))
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            $uniqueID_2 = $row['uniqueID_2'];

            // Below = For each uniqueID_2, generate a PDF.
            if($result1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM myTABLE2 WHERE uniqueID_2 = '" . $uniqueID_2 . "'"))
            {
                while($row1 = $result1->fetch_array())
                {
                    $stuff1 = $row1['stuff1'];
                    $stuff2 = $row1['stuff2'];

                    $fields = array(
                        'Stuff 1'   =>  $stuff1,
                        'Stuff 2'   =>  $stuff2
                    );

                    $pdf = new FPDM('fpdm/template.pdf');
                    $pdf->Load($fields, false);
                    $pdf->Merge();
                    $pdf->Output($uniqueID_2 . ".pdf", "D");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: D makes no sense here if you want to create multiple files, you should be using F

Comment: I was hoping D would just send multiple PDFs to download through the browser. I'll give F a shot now.

Comment: you can't send multiple files with one header

Comment: Thanks, this has worked.

Comment: if you want to send multiple files through the browser just use .zip ;)

Comment: F isn't working